# Error while login into AWS through google in react native

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, google-signin

I working on AWS login through google. I'm following this link https://github.com/patw0929/react-native-cognito-login-example but I'm getting problem with AWS. I have added the lib for aws-sdk-react-native-core as in the link But I'm getting error while running the app.

```
java:45: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Note: C:\Users\krishna21\Awsslogin\node_modules\aws-sdk-react-native-core\android\src\main\java\com\amazonaws\reactnative\core\BackgroundRunner.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':aws-sdk-react-native-core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I have added aws-sdk-react-native-core manually.

Answer (score 0):

John, 
 1. First of all, the library which you are using is old and try using AWS Amplify instead, which is far superior in features and it been tested for security and errors.
 2. In AWS Federated Login can be done in 2 ways, one using Cognito User
    Pool as well as using Cognito Identity Pool. I hope you are using
    Cognito Identity Pool.
 3. Please add the Google Client ID in Edit identity pool->Authentication providers->Google+
 4. Whitelist the domain which you are hitting in Google Developer
    account.

Full documention is here https://itnext.io/google-sign-in-using-aws-amplify-and-amazon-cognito-69cc3bf219ad

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amplify-framework-adds-authentication-features-and-enhancements-for-ios-and-android-mobile-sdks/